# In Power BI, how can you return the category label based on the max value for all categories returned by a measure using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

Looking for some DAX guidance here, to return a text field based on the maximum returned by a measure appplied over that column.

i.e we have table[category_column] and [measure]
and the measure references columns in other tables, with two-sided relationships.

Any help much appreciated, very stuck!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide some data and structure of your table so we understand your starting point and what you try to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading right, I think you want to draw the measure against the column values and return the row with the max of the measure. Something like this?

```
newMeasure = 
    VAR vals = SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Column1], "myMeasure", [Measure])
    VAR measureMax = MAXX(vals, [myMeasure])
    VAR value = CALCULATE(MAXX(FILTER(vals, [myMeasure] = measureMax), [Column1]))
RETURN
    value
```

Comment: Actually it's occurred to me you could probably simplify this by wrapping the summarised table in a TOPN with N =1 and ordered by the measure. Haven't had a chance to test though.

Comment: Thank you Rob C! Firstly apologies for the delay, this project was on hold for a while and only just got to test the suggestion... which worked a treat and even answered the follow-up question which was how to return the nth highest category... which I can do with the TOPN suggestion and changing MAXX to MINX i.e TOPN(5,SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Column1], "myMeasure", [Measure]), [myMeasure]) and then MINX(vals, [myMeasure]) returns the text corresponding to the 5th highest value.

Comment: ps Only thing I had to change was the variable name 'value' which I guess is a reserved keyword

Comment: Thanks for this. Solved the problem I had!

Answer (score 0):

If your column to be used for max is Column1 and your text field is Column2 something like the below could work:

```
Measure = 
VAR Max_Value =max('Table'[Column1])
Return CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[column2]),'Table'[Column1]=Max_value)
```

If this is not what you are looking for you have to explain your requirements in further detail, hopefully with examples.

Comment: Thanks for responding CR7SMS.

Because the values are coming from a measure not a column, this does not work unfortunately.

In your code, substituting max('Table'[Column1]) with max([measure]) fails as max needs a column name.

Comment: How is the measure getting calculated?

Comment: Hi, the measure is fairly complicated - a weighted sum of four other measures, taking the weightings from tables that can be selected in a separate config tab. The 4 measures are also fairy involved (too complicated to paste into here I'd say) and all draw from different tables, but these are connected in the data model by the same category (Column2 as above).